# ASP.NET - write file to fileshare

Tags: asp.net

I am attempting to write a file to a network share.  I am having difficulty getting it to work.  I have investigated on this forum what local account is used to access the share and have found different results:

networkservice (local account)
aspnet (local account)
User network account (when inpersonation is set)
A combination of these depending on stage in the application lifecycle

If I have a fileshare located on a separate server, how do I set it up so that I can access it like this: \servername\share name.  I am using IIS version 6 with anomonous authentication disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
\\serverAddressOrName\share
```

Assuming the permissions are right, you should be able to use this path just as you would a physical path name with the System.IO namespace.

Answer (score 1):

this is a well defined behavior and is by design. Basically you are using a web application to write to network shares which if you step back and see that you are opening a big hole to your resources to world wide web. If this is required and it has to be this way, I would create these files in the local machine path lets say "d:\data\workingfolder". Write a windows service implementing filesystemwatcher monitoring this location. not exhaustive but this service will

1. run under a domain account with access to the network share in question - lets say \\securedmachine\finallocation
2. perform some validation on the files (and contents if need be)
3. port the files from d:\data\workingfolder to \\securedmachine\finallocation

I believe this is robust solution (or workaround if you prefer to say that) to keep your  resources secure and there is a separation of concern to some extent (i.e. business logic in the windows service and data gathering via the UI)

However if you still want asp.net to directly access the network share, then you can still do this using impersonation. ASP.net runs under iusr_user**. this is local account and you cant give network resource access for this account. the solution is well documented http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page

hope this helps and good luck

Krishna

Comment: Thanks.  The web application is deployed to three client PCs.  I like the idea of the FileSystemWatcher, which I could deploy to the three client PC's.  The application is intranet based.  Do you still think there is a risk as per the security loop hole you mentioned?

Comment: if it is an intranet application, then the security issue I raised becomes "noise" - because someone has to break through the firewall to get to your domain resources and if they did, they dont need to use your application to cause harm, they can cause more damage than what your application offers. However I believe it is a good practice to keep web access segrated from network shares. from your comment, I believe I didnt articulate the solution well. you dont need to write 3 file system watchers. just one on the web server is enough which will and can push to the 3 pcs you mentioned

Comment: "you are opening a big hole to your resources to world wide web" - only if A) you allow people to upload any old ASPX page (maybe you're running a  hosting company?) or B) your whole system is badly designed. This really shouldn't be a concern in a well designed infrastructure