# How to Save File to another PC from one PC in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, remote-access

Hello I need to save file instead saving into my PC I want to save that file in connected another Lan PC

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("D:/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

Comment: did you shared another PC's folder? If you did you can use 
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("\\192.168.1.2\test\" + FileUpload1.FileName))

Comment: You could write to a file share (e.g."\\server_name_or_ip\C$\<path>\filename"), but as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383591/asp-net-write-file-to-fileshare) explains, that may not be advisable from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

you can map the lan pc drive to your pc [here how to map](http://www.wikihow.com/Map-a-Network-Drive) but ensure to use a domain account to access it and give it  rights to write on it.

Comment: Failed to map the path '/test (/WIN-PC)AdminLTE-master.zip'.
it gives this error

Comment: try to map drive or folder not a file

Comment: that file i want to save in that "win pc" test folder.

Comment: i have map the test folder from that another pc

Comment: 'Y:/QHAVPAdminLTE-master.zip' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected. got this error

Comment: i Got answer  first share folder  then simply code like    FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"Y:" + FileUpload1.FileName);